# Why Does (Windows 7) Libraries/Pictures Have A Date In The Future?

Tags: windows-7

My wife's Windows 7 laptop shows Libraries/Pictures with a date of 6/10/2014 or later. This represents one day's worth of saved images. This has been going on a year, and always shows one month ahead of today's date. Tomorrow this date will advance one day.

Is this a problem and can it be corrected?

If it is not a problem, why is a future date showing?

If there is something an answerer would like to see added to the OP, I'll happily go research it and add it. I'm stumped, and no longer know enough about Windows to try to monkey with the properties.

Comment: What is the date in the picture's meta data?

Comment: If they're taken on your camera, what's the date on the camera?

Comment: These pictures came off the internet on one day about a year ago. How does one find the meta data? It was modified in February 2014.

Comment: It was taken on 01/01/4501. That explains a lot. Can it be fixed, or just ignore it? These pictures are from Picasa, and they all have the same whacky date.

Comment: Maybe Picasa corrupts the EXIF data

Comment: Suggest someone provide an answer out of the comments. These are good comments, and basically answered my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a file has a date that is set in the future, it means whatever device took the picture or saved the picture had the computer/phone/camera date set wrong.  The only issues I've ever ran into with this being an issue is when I sort a folders contents by date and everything is not where I expect it to be.  However, that won't prevent the image/file from working any different generally.  It can be fixed by opening the picture in say photoshop or some other image editing software and re-saving the file to the date you want it set to (by default whatever your current time/date is on your computer).

There can be multiple dates associated with a file however so be aware of that.  Date created, and date modified are the ones that come off the top of my head.  Date modified will be what you change if you re-save a file.  Image files do contain extra meta data however and possibly other dates but none of them will affect the image being view-able.

This could provide additional ideas on what you can and cannot change:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Change-the-properties-for-a-file